# how to view a tableview controller when a button is clicked in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

While clicking a Button i need to view a table view container in next window. I tried it by story board connecting the button with file owner and viewed the table but i need to do it as program. I was thinking to give some event handlers to button and view the table. Is it possible to do so. I attached the image for reference,

[image: From button to Table view]
I used this code,

```
TableViewController *yourTableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navigationController pushViewController:yourTableViewController animated:YES];
```

in the " viewDidLoad() " but it doesn't shown. Do i need to configure any in storyboard to do it. Kindly suggest me.

Comment: put in the button that u are clicking instead of the viewdidload.

Comment: so you saying me to write an IBAction in class right ? If so how can i connect the IBAction to that button in storyboard. In otherway how i refer the IBAction name to the specific button in storyboard

Comment: for the first two question, it is a yes. you don't need to refer to the button in the storyboard, all you need to do is press control and pull the function over the button in the storyboard

Comment: Thank you, what kind of definition should i write in that action function to say it click and open the table..

Comment: watch this: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uitableview/

Comment: Thanks a lot Lakesh, i will verify it.

Comment: i will add comments as a solution... please upvote it..

Comment: i don have enough reputation to upvote need 15 but i have 12 sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

put in the button that u are clicking instead of the viewdidload.

watch this: [mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uitableview](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uitableview)